# What are the hiddent buttons in Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I accidentally press <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times in my browser and find out the three hidden buttons right under the logo:

[image]

Is this a bug? If not, how to access it by mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. Accessibility features are for users using assertive technologies such as screen readers, so mouse usage isn't expected.

You can read more in the [Accessibility in Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/181196?hl=en-AU) page (one of the first links to appear while tabbing):

> **Accessibility in Google Search**
>
> After you search, the search results page is organized so that you can easily navigate it with assistive technology, like screen readers and keyboard-only.
>
> **Accessibility links on search results pages**
>
> On a computer, you'll find 3 accessibility links at the top of a search results page: Skip to main content, Accessibility help, and Accessibility feedback.
>
> - With a keyboard: Press the Tab key until you reach the link you want. Then press the Enter key.
> - With a screen reader: Use your screen reader's quick navigation controls.